# How to set Spring application context through setter or constructor in another class

Tags: spring

I have a Spring class.

```
@Service("dbManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseManager {

    GenericXmlApplicationContext context;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public DatabaseManager(GenericXmlApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

        ....
} //end of class DatabaseManager
```

I have SpringUtil class

```
public class SpringUtil {

    public static GenericXmlApplicationContext loadSpringContext(String springXmlFile) {    

        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load(springXmlFile);
        context.refresh();

        return context;

    } //end of loadSpringContext()

} //end of class SpringUtil
```

Now in main i am using some thing like

```
public class Regulator  {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Test test = new Test;
        test.start();

    } //end of main()

} //end of class Regulator
```

Here is test class

```
public class Test {

    public void start() {

        String springXmlFile = "classpath:spring/plcb-app-context-xml.xml";
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = SpringUtil.loadSpringContext(springXmlFile);

    } //end of reportStudent()

 } //end of class Test
```

But i am getting error that

```
Could not instantiate bean class [...DatabaseManager]: No default constructor 
found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
...DatabaseManager.<init>()
```

I want that when `DatabaseManager` class created then spring context taht i am creating using `SpringUtil.loadSpringContext(springXmlFile)` must pass to it. How can i do it ?

Thanks

**Edit
-------------------**

```
public void switchDataSource(DatabaseType databaseType) {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;

    if (databaseType == DatabaseType.LEGACY) {

        dataSource = (DriverManagerDataSource)context.getBean("myLegacyDataSource");

    } else if (databaseType == DatabaseType.LS360) {

        dataSource = (DriverManagerDataSource)context.getBean("myLs360DataSource");

    }

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = context.getBean("myEmf", LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class);
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Object> getResultList(String query, Class mappingClass) throws Exception {

    Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query, mappingClass);

    return  emQuery.getResultList();

} //end of findTraineeFromLegacy()
```

Actually i have these two methods in my DatabaseManager class. I am setting context so i can get bean from the context in `switchDataSource()` method.

One thing that i can do is remove instance filed and change the method to

```
public void switchDataSource(DatabaseType databaseType, GenericXmlApplicationContext context) {
     ....
}
```

This is why i am doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a spring context in your class? You should be able to use dependency injection for whatever resource you need.

Comment: @Max what do you mean by `dependency injection for whatever resource you need`. You mean in `DatabaseManager class` create field of type `Test class`. In `Test` class provide getter and setter for `context` and in `DatabaseManager class` inject Test Reference ?

Comment: Ok, let's start small. What will you do with the context in DatabaseManager?

Answer (score 2):

Have a no-arg constructor for DatabaseManager.

Implements ApplicationContextAware in DatabaseManager.  Spring will know this bean needs to be notified of the application context:

```
@Service("dbManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseManager implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    public DatabaseManager() {...}

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        this.context = appContext;
    }
} //end of class DatabaseManager
```

however, double think if you really need that injected.  In most case you are doing something wrong.

---

Update:

For your requirement in your update, which you want your DB Manager to switch datasource base on input type, although it doesn't seems very normal doing such thing, you can simply have your DB Manager injected with a Map and do whatever you want, instead of injecting the app context.

```
@Service("dbManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseManager implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Resource("&emfBean")
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean;

    @Resource("dbManagerDsMap")
    private Map<DatabaseType, Datasource> dsMapping;

    public DatabaseManager() {...}

    public void switchDataSource(DatabaseType databaseType) {
        emfBean.setDatasource(dsMapping.get(databaseType));
    }

} //end of class DatabaseManager
```

However I strongly suggest you not doing such thing.  Consider having individual entityManagerFactory for each DB you are connecting to, and use the correct emf to connect to DB, instead doing this weird switching logic.  I believe it is not supposed to be changed after your application start.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. I think you meant `@Resource` instead of `@Override`.

Comment: Or you forgot to implement `ApplicationContextAware`.

Comment: @Max my fault: I forgot to implement ApplicationContextAware (though I am describing that in my answer). Sorry for the copy and paste problem :P (And thanks Bart for updating the answer)